# Vehicle's interaction with the edge Cloud using Sumo and NS3

Tags: sumo, ns-3

Lately, I have been interested in evaluating the vehicle interaction with the Edge Cloud (Latency matter). I am thinking about using Sumo traces in a Ns3 simulation, but the problem is that all what I found are tutoriels simulating Vanet Communication : Vehicles with Vehicles. My question is : Is there a way to represent the edge cloud (As a calculating node) in this environment, for example a static node placed in the map, not moving but interacting with vehicles. I don't want to work on something already doomed to fail and thank you for your insights.

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

An edge cloud can be represented by a static node anywhere on your scenario (wherever you want it placed).
In NS-3 you can have multiple mobility for different nodes, i.e., have nodes representing cars or pedestrians being mobile, and your cloud node or Wi-Fi AP being static.

Can you share your code?